# Are there already statistics about the spread of common viral diseases in the Covid-19 pandemic era?

Tags: virus, disease-transmission, statistics, covid-19-datasets

Are there already public statistics regarding the spread of other viral diseases since the beginning of the Covid-19 pandemic, and the application of mandatory protection rules (e.g. protection masks, alcoholic gel, social distancing…) ?  I would expect lower rates than usual, but I know for a fact they're far from extinct (just got a light family rhinopharyngitis…).

Comment: I think it will be a while before we know the answer to this so it may not be answerable now, but I also think it's an interesting question that will probably be answerable in the near future. My bet would be we'll see lower rates in areas with high compliance and no change in non-compliant areas.